# Scraping in R, cannot get "onclick" attribute

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'm scraping the NFL website with R. R might not be the best to do this but that is not my question here.
I can usually get everything I want but for the first time I got a problem.
In the present case I want to get info from let's say, this page

http://www.nfl.com/player/j.j.watt/2495488/profile

The info I want to get is there

```
<a href="draft" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.nfl.com/player/j.j.watt/2495488/draft_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Draft</a>
```

Using xPathSapply(parsedPage,xmlGettAttr, name="onclick") I get only NULL... and I do not get the reason why.

I could retrieve the information elsewhere in the code and then paste to recover the address but I find it much easier and clearer to get it at once.
How can I get this, using R, eventually C. I do not know much about JavaScript, I would be happy to avoid this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In a general point view, I used both XML and xml2 and find xml2 most suitable for debugging. Try the function `xml_attr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there are no "onclick"-attributes in the sourcecode: See (in Chrome)
`view-source:http://www.nfl.com/player/j.j.watt/2495488/profile`

The onclick-attributes are added via javascript. Because of that you need a parser that executes the JS.

In **R** you can you `RSelenium` for that as follows:

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.nfl.com/player/j.j.watt/2495488/profile")
doc <- remDr$getPageSource()

require(rvest)
doc <- read_html(doc[[1]])
doc %>% html_nodes(".HOULink") %>% xml_attr("onclick")

remDr$close()
#shutdown
browseURL("http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer")
```

For me this resulted in:

```
[1] "s_objectID=\"http://www.nfl.com/teams/houstontexans/profile?team=HOU_1\";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true"                 
[2] "s_objectID=\"http://www.houstontexans.com/_2\";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true"                                           
[3] "s_objectID=\"http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2015122004/2015/REG15/texans@colts/watch_1\";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true"  
...
```

You can also use a headless browser like phantomjs see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry I could not answer earlier. I still need to understand the way html_nodes work. From what I read, it looks like one can use the path but I could not find the way yet. How would you look for this //div[id('player-profile-tabs')]/ul/li/a  ? Also I had problems to connect to the server "Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) " in the beginning but I could solve this.

Comment: Have a look at `?html_nodes`. You can either use a css selector or an xpath. For getting the css-selector google for selectorgadget

Comment: Thanks again, I could find what I was looking for. Maybe my last question would be: As I can basically this way scrap everything on the page, I could use this even for other information instead of xpathSApply I am actually using. Is one of them more efficient than the other?

Comment: you can use `xpathSApply` from the `XML`-Package as well. Have a look at https://github.com/hadley/xml2 - there is a comparison of the `XML` and the `xml2` package... (The `rvest` package is just a convinience-wrapper around xml2)

Comment: @Floo0 Thanks for the answer, I was wondering, Is it impossible to get "onclick" attribute with rvest ? and 'RSelenium' is the only option?